# Каков статус ресурса "Грамота.ру"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Я постоянно пользуюсь словарями на этом сайте, также иногда  просматриваю ответы на вопросы.

Но вот что мне интересно: эти ответы составлены на основе имеющихся официальных источников по правописанию или сайт имеет право  эти источники редактировать и дополнять. Обычно там дают только ответы, объяснений мало, ссылок тоже.

Правомерно ли при ответах на вопросы ссылаться на этот сайт как на официальный источник?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не может иметь однозначного ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, но мне кажется, что я получила однозначный ответ: "Они не редактируют правила, а сами ссылаются на готовые правила".  Таким образом, сайт ценится очень высоко, но он только помогает разбираться в официальных сводах, не  являясь при этом  источником новых правил.

Comment: @Arina, а вы, простите, серьезно думали, что "Грамота" имеет некие привилегии хотя бы по редактированию правил? Они есть только у ИРЯ РАН - да и то весьма куцые.  Про "ценится высоко" в своем ответе подробно расписал.

Comment: Кто может редактировать правила? Я, к примеру,  не знаю, насколько официальным является свод Лопатина, разве он утвержден на государственном уровне? Но  в ПАС достаточно внесенных им изменений (например, он отменил дефис в сочетании старик-сторож). Получается такая ползучая реформа правописания. А ведь вариант  его реформы критиковали многие. (Для примера  могу вспомнить написание слова "миллионоголосый". Оно было сначала неверно  исправлено, а теперь опять пишется по-старому).  Я думала, что,  может,  и Грамота  дает собственное толкования правил, которые противоречат официальным текстам.

Comment: «...но мне кажется, что я получила однозначный ответ». Когда ответ однозначный, то уж нет места сомнениям. В любом случае вопрос привёл — сами видите — к обсуждению. А для этого есть Мета: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сегодняшний день - это самый авторитетный сайт по русскому языку наряду с Граммой.ру. У сайта есть редакционный совет,который возглавляет ректор Государственного института русского языка им. А. С. Пушкина, вице-президент Российского общества преподавателей русского языка и литературы, доктор филологических наук Юрий Прохор.

Является лауреатом премии Рунета.

Из Википедии.

Среди многих русскоязычных пользователей Интернета информация портала считается **достаточно авторитетной** при проверке правописания русских слов. Однако нормы, указанные составителями других словарей разных лет издания (Розенталя, Зализняка и других), могут несколько различаться.

Председатель Общества любителей российской словесности, лингвист и общественный деятель В. П. Нерознак в 2003 году отмечал:[12]

Этот информационный портал, посвящённый русской словесности, был учреждён Министерством печати. В составе редакционного совета — крупнейшие специалисты по русскому языку. В портале выложен целый ряд словарей. Ежедневно его посещают более десяти тысяч человек. Кстати, очень активно пользуются порталом за рубежом: США, Германия, Израиль, республики ближнего зарубежья. Если набраться терпения и распечатать весь портал, получится книга в сто тысяч страниц — это 500 мегабайт информации.

См.также здесь:[О портале](http://www.gramota.ru/gramota/about/)

Хотя там тоже порой ошибаются, в общем, думаю, стоит  ссылаться на этот сайт как на официальный источник.

Comment: Серж,  о Грамоте.ру везде положительные отзывы,  но почему они далеко не всегда указывают ссылки на правила, если они только объясняют эти правила, а не редактируют их. А то у пользователей возникает впечатление, что это независимый портал с таким же статусом, как у официальных правил.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Часто они не указывают ссылки. Но если вы заметили, большую часть вопросов составляют запятые и вопросы про провописание. На некоторые из них не стоит даже давать ссылки.

Comment: Они не редактируют правила, а сами ссылаются на готовые правила. Об этом они говорили сами. Их минус в том, что они отвечают на столь примитивные вопросы, на которые, например, можно получить ответ, заглянув в словарь. Действительно сложных и интересных вопросов очень мало. Плюс от трудно получить ответ.

Comment: Вот я им несколько раз писал по поводу ошибок в словаре.ВИДНО. I. нареч., в функц. сказ. Можно видеть, рассмотреть. С горы далеко в. ***Дом виден издалека***.Обратите внимание: в выделенным примере слово не наречие, а прилагательное. Еще примере: МАЦОНИ, неизм.; ср. [груз. mac'oni] На Кавказе: ***кислое молоко***. Поужинать хлебом с мацони. Но мацони не кислое молоко, а кисломолочный продукт, получаемый путем заквашивания. Писал, чтобы исправили. Были еще вопросы, касательно словаря их сайта, но ни разу не ответили.

Comment: Да, здесь на сайте порядки построже:  просят давать ссылки и приводить текстовые  примеры. Да,  я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Arina давать ссылки в ответах не обязательно, но желательно указывать откуда сведения, особенно, если вопрос спорный.

Comment: Да, спасибо, понятно, только мне кажется, что ответ с ссылками и примерами вызывает большее доверие, иначе он выглядит просто как  мнение отвечающего по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 3):

Никакого официального статуса у "Грамоты" нет.
Она часто называет себя государственным или того хлеще - всероссийским ресурсом, но это не подтверждается её правовым статусом. Это ООО.

В отношении ответов "Справки". Их там дают обычные студенты-практиканты. Так что воля ваша, как к ним относиться. Владимир Пахомов (главред) всего лишь кандидат наук. Это разумеется, не значит, что ресурс сам по себе никчемный, но вы-то об авторитетности, даже официальности спрашиваете.

Вообще в сфере лингвистики не принято говорить о каких-то "официальных" источниках. Есть источники нормативные (словари, своды правил), приравниваемые к нормативным (Розенталь и отчасти - Лопатин) и просто авторитетные (Еськова, Валгина, ну и другие). "Грамота" ни к одним из них не относится.

По секрету скажу, "Грамота" вообще переживает не самые лучшие времена. После смерти её создателя, Анатолия Кормилицина, её сильно лихорадит.

> Грамоте.ру везде положительные отзывы, но почему они далеко не всегда
>   указывают ссылки на правила, если они только объясняют эти правила,

Даже если это так (в чем лично я крепко сомневаюсь), то это не делает статус официальным. Насколько понимаю, вы, говоря о грамоте, имеете в виду только "Справку". Так вот, там часто просто нелепость на нелепости сидит.

По поводу ссылок. Я могу согласиться, что не на все вопросы нужны ссылки. Они и здесь-то не всегда нужны, но тут уж модераторы переусердствовали. Впрочем, лучше уж так, чем наоборот. Если человеку нужно решить сиюминную проблему, а источник "откровения" при необходимости легко находится, можно и не злоупотреблять ссылками. Но они безусловно нужны, когда речь идет о каком-то полемическом соображении, используемом как аргумент в неком, пусть и заочном, споре...

Не могу еще одну мысль не высказать. Словари на "Грамоте" - авторские. Грамоте не принадлежат. Серж ломится в открытую дверь. Внесение изменений в словарь - не их прерогатива. Писать надо Лопатину или Кузнецову. А грамота отвечает только за опечатки, расхождения с бумажной версией. Вы не будете предъявлять претензии к типографии, если автор не считает ваш вариант трактовки слова мацони верным? Так при чем тут вообще "Грамота"?

> Я постоянно пользуюсь словарями на этом сайте,

Имеете право. Словари достаточно авторитетные. Только имейте в виду, что ссылаться надо на сам словарь, автора его, грамота тут - последняя инстанция, вроде стрелочника. Или типографского наборщика.

> также иногда просматриваю ответы на вопросы.

А вот у вопросов статуса нет никакого. Ну не намного больше, чем у любого посетителя лингвистического ресурса.

Comment: @ddbug - спасибо, давно уже исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересное мнение. Я почему-то думала,что там работают по крайней мере кандидаты наук.  А почему так популярна Грамота.ру? Вот Вы назвали Еськову, Валгину,  но их знают мало. У них есть в открытом доступе материалы по правописанию, сравнимые с Розенталем?

Comment: @Мимоходов, я прекрасно знаю, что внесение изменения в словарь не их прерогатива. Но  они могут обратиться к авторам словаря и с их позволения внести изменения. Еще и учитывая,что Кузнецов научный консультант портала Грамота.ру.

Comment: Да и потом, вы думаете, Кузнецову и Лопатину могут написать простые пользователи,как мы?

Comment: А по поводу того,что "у вопросов статуса нет никакого. Ну не намного больше, чем у любого посетителя лингвистического ресурса", не согласен. Они смогут ответить на вопросы, на которые вряд ли сможет ответить любой посетитель лингвистического ресурса.

Comment: @Серж при чем тут "простые пользователи"? Если вы считаете, что в словаре ошибка, то писать навдо составителю словаря, а не стрелочнику. "Грамота" за вас это сделать может (иногда и делала), но не обязана. О письмах составителям словарей (и не только) послушайте Сафронову https://youtu.be/Gzv0gSO0kaY

Comment: @Arina Вадгина - автор основного учебника по синтаксису. Еськова  - соавтор Аванесова, после него фактический руководитель коллектива, выпускавшего его словарь. Я еще Шведову забыл - это постоянный соавтор Розенталя.

Comment: *А почему так популярна Грамота.ру?* - а я бы не сказал, что она сейчас так "популярна". Индексы цитирования в интернете падают катастофически. Посмотрите, на каким местах "грамота" в результатах поиска гугла или яндекса. Да и эти-то места - во многом следствие той ситуации, которая было лет 15 назад, когда "Грамота" была единственной и неповторимой.

Comment: @ Мимоходов,вы правы. Иногда делала! Поэтому писал. Думал, они обратятся  к автору словаря.